# UDP Sockets - One server, mulitple clients. Not sent to all clients

Tags: c, sockets, udp, winsock2

I am writing in windows, using Visual Studio, and am trying to have one application use UDP sockets to broadcast a message to other applications.  This must be done with UDP sockets.

It works well with just one client, but it does not when I add another client, and all listen on the same port.

TX (Server)

```
/* Example from: http://matrixsust.blogspot.com/2011/10/udp-server-client-in-c.html */

/* Use legacy sockets */
#define _WINSOCK_DEPRECATED_NO_WARNINGS

/* Add a linker to ws2_32.lib, the Winsock2 library */
#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")

#include <stdio.h>
#include <winsock2.h>


int main()
{
    WSADATA wsaData;
    int sock, sin_size;
    struct sockaddr_in server_addr;
    struct hostent* host;
    char send_data[1024];
    boolean keep_running = 1;
    unsigned int cmd_no_block_arg = 1;
    int SERVER_PORT;


    /* Obtain a valid port */
    printf("Enter a port number to connect to (i.e. 7171):\n");
    scanf_s("%d", &SERVER_PORT);
     
    if ((SERVER_PORT < 1) || (SERVER_PORT > 665534))
    {
        SERVER_PORT = 7171;
    }

    /* Initialize Winsock version 2.2 */
    WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);




    /* CLIENT SIDE */
    host = (struct hostent*) gethostbyname((char*)"127.0.0.1");


    if ((sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP)) == -1)
    {
        perror("socket");
        exit(1);
    }

    /* SETUP */
    server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server_addr.sin_port = htons(SERVER_PORT);
    server_addr.sin_addr = *((struct in_addr*)host->h_addr);
   
    memset(server_addr.sin_zero, 0, sizeof(server_addr.sin_zero));
    sin_size = sizeof(struct sockaddr);


    /* Bind the socket, then enable non-blocking semantics */
    if ((ioctlsocket(sock, FIONBIO, &cmd_no_block_arg) == SOCKET_ERROR))
    {
        printf("Could not non-bind socket. Error Code %i\n", WSAGetLastError());
    }



    

    while (keep_running)
    {

        printf("Type Something (q or Q to quit):");
        gets_s(send_data, sizeof(send_data));

        if ((strcmp(send_data, "q") == 0) || strcmp(send_data, "Q") == 0)
        {
            keep_running = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            sendto(sock, send_data, strlen(send_data), 0, (struct sockaddr*) & server_addr, sizeof(struct sockaddr));
        }

    } // While

}
```

RX (Clients)

```
/* Example from: http://matrixsust.blogspot.com/2011/10/udp-server-client-in-c.html */

#define _WINSOCK_DEPRECATED_NO_WARNINGS

/* Add a linker to ws2_32.lib, the Winsock2 library */
#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")

#include <stdio.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    WSADATA wsaData;
    int sock;
    int addr_len, bytes_read;
    char recv_data[1024], send_data[1024];
    struct sockaddr_in server_addr, client_addr;
    int                sharing_flag = 1; /* Allow sharing */
    unsigned int       non_block_flag = 1; 
    unsigned int       SERVER_PORT = 7171;
    

    /* Obtain a valid port to connect to */
    printf("Enter a port number to connect to (i.e. 7171):\n");
    scanf_s("%d", &SERVER_PORT);

    if ((SERVER_PORT < 1) || (SERVER_PORT > 65535))
    {
        SERVER_PORT = 7171;
    }


    /* Initialize Winsock version 2.2 */
    WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);


    /* SERVER SIDE: bind(), recvfrom(), sendto() */
    if ((sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP)) == -1) {
        perror("Socket");
        exit(1);
    }

    server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server_addr.sin_port = htons(SERVER_PORT);
    
    server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
   
    memset(server_addr.sin_zero, 0, sizeof(server_addr.sin_zero));
    
    /* Eliminates "ERROR on binding: Address already in use" error */
    if (setsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, (void*)&sharing_flag, sizeof(sharing_flag)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        printf("Error on socket opt: %i\n", WSAGetLastError());

    }

    if ((bind(sock, (struct sockaddr*) & server_addr, sizeof(struct sockaddr)) == SOCKET_ERROR) ||
        (ioctlsocket(sock, FIONBIO, &non_block_flag) == SOCKET_ERROR))
    {
        printf("Error on socket bind: %i\n", WSAGetLastError());
 
    }

    addr_len = sizeof(struct sockaddr);

    printf("\nUDPServer Waiting for client on port %i\n", SERVER_PORT);

   
    while (1)
    {
        
        bytes_read = recvfrom(sock, recv_data, 1024, 0, (struct sockaddr*) & client_addr, &addr_len);
        
        if (bytes_read >= 0)
        {
            recv_data[bytes_read] = '\0';
            
            printf("\n(%s , %d) said : ", inet_ntoa(client_addr.sin_addr), ntohs(client_addr.sin_port));
            printf("%s\n", recv_data);
                      
            fflush(stdout);

        } /* if we read in bytes */

    } /* while */

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is `665534` a typo?  max value I believe is `65535`

Comment: You are correct, 65535 is the limit, small typo

Comment: Where do you enable broadcast? Or where does the recipient provide a copy to the other recipient? Where's the code to do any kind of broadcasting?! You have no code anywhere to produce more than a single message when you send. Where do you think the data is being duplicated or sent to both recipients exactly? UDP has broadcast capability, but by default it is unicast.

Comment: By enabling broadcasts on my server: '''    int broadcast_mode = 1;
    if (setsockopt (sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BROADCAST, (void*) &broadcast_mode, sizeof (broadcast_mode)) < 0) {
        printf ("setsockopt error\n");
        exit (1);
    }'''
The result is the same, only one 'client' will receive the print the message

Comment: Figured it out.  Needed to add in this on the tx side:  server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_BROADCAST;